# python subprocess call ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, python-2.7, nlp, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run alt discourse parser tree in ubuntu 14.04 (http://alt.qcri.org/tools/discourse-parser/)

Everything compiled successfully, but during runtime it shows the following error.

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-classpath', 'Tools/grmm/class:Tools/grmm/lib/mallet-deps.jar:Tools/grmm/lib/grmm-deps.jar', 'edu.umass.cs.mallet.grmm.learning.AcrfForTestJoty', '--testing', 'tmp_sen.feat', '--model-file', 'dcrf.sen.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1

I just want to know what this error means, as well as the command and arguments  that are shown in the error.  All the necessary jar files are present in their respective locations.

Comment: that's not a python problem. your external java app failed, and python's telling you about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @MarkB mentioned in his comment this is not really a Python error message, but instead is Python simply explaining what command it ran to execute a Java program, and its return value, and that something went wrong during its execution.

This message shows that the Java program returned with a value of 1.  Usually, a program exiting with a non-zero status means that something went wrong.  You will need to look up what the value of 1 for this application means (if anything).

To explain the error message piece by piece:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) subprocess.

Python ran the process 'subprocess' and an error was thrown on line 540 (this is irrelevant, since it's just internal Python stuff).  This was an error thrown by the called Java process, **not** the internal Python stuff.

> CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-classpath', 'Tools/grmm/class:Tools/grmm/lib/mallet-deps.jar:Tools/grmm/lib/grmm-deps.jar', 'edu.umass.cs.mallet.grmm.learning.AcrfForTestJoty', '--testing', 'tmp_sen.feat', '--model-file', 'dcrf.sen.gz']

The error type thrown was of [CalledProcessError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions), meaning the called process didn't return zero, and it's showing you the command used to start the external [Java] application.  The command is simply `java`, and the options & arguments are as follows (in order)

- `'-classpath', 'Tools/grmm/class:Tools/grmm/lib/mallet-deps.jar:Tools/grmm/lib/grmm-deps.jar'`  Overwrite the default classpath environment variable for this JVM session using the 3 paths shown separated by colons (:).
- `edu.umass.cs.mallet.grmm.learning.AcrfForTestJoty` this is the class that contains a main method and will be invoked
- `--testing, 'tmp_sen.feat'` is a custom argument passed to main method in the Java program
- `'--model-file', 'dcrf.sen.gz'` is another custom argument passed to the main method in the Java program

Finally, this line

> returned non-zero exit status 1

Is the return value of the Java program.  It's giving you a heads up that it did not exit with 0 (success), and instead experienced some sort of issue with the error code of 1.  This may mean something if the Java program exits with different error codes, or it may just mean it exited with a generic issue, but it could be anything.

Long story short:  You need to either make sure you're passing the right values to the Java program.  If this is your own Java program then I'd recommend debugging it.  If not, you should run it directly (without Python) with the same arguments: `--testing tmp_sen.feat` & `--model-file dcrf.sen.gz` to find out if those arguments themselves are the issue.  Hopefully, this way you'll get a clearer error on what's going wrong in your Java program.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply..i corrected that..but now i am having another similar problem involving perl subprocess..please help me out on this..     File "/home/prasenjit/Desktop/Shared/nlp/Discourse_Parser_Dist/TopicFeatures.py", line 31, in computeLexChains
    subprocess.check_output(['perl', lex_ch, chfile_in, chfile_out])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['perl', 'lexChain.pl', 'tmp.ch_in', 'tmp.chn']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Comment: @Prasenjitdey My pleasure.  Please accept this answer if it answered your original question.  SO rules state that separate questions should be posted separately, but essentially this is the exact same issue.  Everything on the python end is good, but the Perl program is erroring out causing a return value of 2.  I can't help you in as much detail for this question because I am not familiar with Perl.  You should find out what the return error of 2 represents to get to the bottom of it.